# Type object 'SGP30' has no attribute 'closed'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to send to Thingspeak the data I take from the sensors on my Raspberry pi.
I really don't know how to use python, so I only "mix" some codes I found on the web.

This code works one time, and the data is sent one time, but the the "loop" stops and comes the error in the title.
for sure something is wrong with the "with". i don't know how to close the file
Can you help me?
this is the code:

```py
import httplib
import urllib
import time
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
from sgp30 import SGP30
from smbus import SMBus
key = "xxxxxxx"  
smbus = SMBus(1)    

def sensors():
    with SGP30(smbus) as chip:
        while True:
            aq = chip.measure_air_quality()
            VOC = aq.voc_ppb
            CO2 = aq.co2_ppm
            hum, temp = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)
            params = urllib.urlencode({'field1': temp, 'field2': hum,'field3': VOC, 'field4': CO2,'key':key })                                  
            headers = {"Content-typZZe": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/plain"}
            conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.thingspeak.com:80")
            try:
                conn.request("POST", "/update", params, headers)
                response = conn.getresponse()
                print (temp, hum, VOC, CO2)
                print (response.status, response.reason)
                data = response.read()
                conn.close()
            except:
                print ("connection failed")        
            break
    chip.closed
if __name__ == "__main__":
        while True:
            sensors()
```

Comment: Be careful, bare except statements are bad practice.

Comment: what? i don't get it